# What is the simplest way to implement an instant messaging contact page on my website?

Tags: user-engagement

I'd like to have a page that communicates directly to some IM service that I will generally be able to be logged into.

E.g. I am on gtalk all the time, I'd like people to be able to get in touch with me via the website.  (the specific protocol isn't that important, of course)

What would be the simplest set of technologies to implement that (me at my computer, a guest viewer on a page of my website)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Google Talk chatback widget](http://googletalk.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-talk-chatback.html). You just have to [embed a HTML snippet](http://www.google.com/talk/service/badge/New) that they provide.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, simple, and excellent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These both have dedicated clients, not jabber (gtalk) clients, but we've had great success with:

- [Click and Chat](http://www.clickandchat.com/) (A paid, but cheap, hosted service)
- [Livezilla](http://www.livezilla.net/) (A free, self-hosted service)

The advantage of both of those over Google Talk is that these give you real-time stats about your visits. You can watch, in real time, where your visitors are browsing on your site and when they click the link to chat, you get their full site browsing history at your fingertips, so you can say "I see you're looking at our [x] product, can I give you more information about it", etc.

Comment: Interesting, though that's a level of depth that I'm not really looking for, I'm fine with them communicating their needs to me as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this link will work for you, it has various chat programs for websites and blogs.

http://im.about.com/od/resources/a/imwidgets.htm

http://www.99chats.com/

http://site.bumpin.com/

I have used Bumpin, beacause it provides you good admin control, no spam messages on your e-mail id, you can control your users chat and also you can have same account for multiple website.